# Trouble creating covered query with compound index

Tags: mongodb

My index:

```
{
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
                "a" : 1,
                "b" : 1,
                "c" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "Pepper.test",
        "name" : "a_1_b_1_c_1"
}
```

Sample record:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("527a8477a868a04479a56a56"), "a" : 1, "b" : 1, "c" : 1, "x" : -1 }
```

My query:

```
db.test.find({a: 1, b: 1, c: 1},{_id: 0, x:0})
```

Output from explain():

```
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor a_1_b_1_c_1",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 1,
        "nscannedObjects" : 1,
        "nscanned" : 1,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 1,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 0,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "a" : [
                        [
                                1,
                                1
                        ]
                ],
                "b" : [
                        [
                                1,
                                1
                        ]
                ],
                "c" : [
                        [
                                1,
                                1
                        ]
                ]
        },
        "server" : "ip-x-x-x-x:27017"
}
```

From the documentation it would seem like a test like this should have "indexOnly" reported as true in the explain, but it does not. Am I doing something wrong, or misunderstanding a limitation of covered queries? This data set is merely a sample to show the problem, but it's the same basic structure as my real data and indexes.

Doing a test, if I remove the x field entirely from my data, AND specify to include a,b,c and exclude _id it works. It seems that I am unable to do a covered index if you have any field in your data set that is not a part of the index. I tried including a,b,c, and excluding _id and x, but mongo provides an error stating:

> "$err" : "You cannot currently mix including and excluding fields.
>   Contact us if this is an issue."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query's `explain` shows `"indexOnly": true`:

```
db.test.find({a: 1, b: 1, c: 1}, {_id: 0, a: 1, b: 1, c: 1})
```

As @Sammaye mentions in the comments, your projection needs to specify the complete set of *included* fields as just excluding the fields *you* know aren't in the index doesn't mean that there isn't some doc in your collection with some other field that's not in the index.

Comment: Interesting, so by forcing the include of a,b, and c, it will automatically exclude x? You're right this seems to work and shows "indexOnly": true

Comment: @TomSwifty Right.  Once you explicitly include a field, all other fields are excluded except for `_id`.

Comment: I can say why the query in the OP question didn't work, with the two fields omitted MongoDB still cannot know if the index was covered without looking at the documents

Answer (score 1):

You cannot choose to exclude anything else if you already chose to exclude "_id".